# New in coding, works in codeblocks but not in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, codeblocks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{ long i, s, t;
    double sum, current ;
    t= 1;
    i= 1;
    s= 3;
    sum= 0.0;

    do {
        current = (1/  (((double) i) * ((double) s)));
        sum = sum + current;
        i=i+2;
        s=s+2;
        t=t+1;



    } while (current > 0.0e-9); //potato pc //
  printf("Summed %8ld terms, sum is %10.8f\n", t, sum);

}
```

When I run it in code blocks it takes about 20 sec to build and run, but when I try it on VS Code and Run it nothing happens. My university needs it to run in VS Code and in Linux, so I remotely connect to Linux with SSH (I also have WSL, but I have the same problem)
Can someone help me on what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: This is what the program is trying to do]

The problem was that I wrote `(current > 0.0e-9)` while I made the program solve this. Yea... I am a Math genius its seems. So I change the 0 to 1, and it works now `(current > 1.0e-9)`.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that VSCode can't compile code on it's own. There are some code editors, known as IDE (Integrated Development Environment) that have their own built-in compilers, such as CodeBlocks. When you hit "run" in CodeBlocks, it compiles your code and then runs the output.

In VSCode, you have no compiler, and when you hit "run", what is really happening is that you are debugging your code, but since your code is not executable by your machine yet, it apparently does nothing.

You can try to compile your code manually, with compilers such as [GCC](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compiling-a-cplusplus-program-with-gcc) and then run it. This is the approach I use when working with C++ on Linux and you are not using an IDE.

You can look for an extension that compiles your code directly from VSCode, although I don't know if there really is an extension that does that (I have to say that I don't do much C++ programming).